# Quadratics & algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Z is proportional to X.

When X = -4, Z = 2.

Enter the value of X required to give Z = -2.

1. Y is proportional to X.

When X = 2, Y = 1.

Find the value of X required to give Y = -4.

1. Z is proportional to (X - 2). When X = 1, Z = 1. Enter the value of X required to give Z = -2.
2. Y is proportional to (1 - X). When X = 2, Y = -2. Find the value of X required to give Y = 6.
3. Y is inversely proportional to X. When X = 2, Y = 1.

Find the value of X required to give Y = 6.

[Express your as a decimal correct to 2sf]

6.C is inversely proportional to A^2. When A = 0.1, C = 50. Find C when A = .02.

This might help =IMPORTANT NOTE In the following, x^2, x^3, mean "x squared", "x cubed", respectively. Generally, a^n means "a to the power n".

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$x\;\;\text{is proportional to}\;\;z\;\;\text{means that there exists a constant $\;k\;$ s.t.}\;\;x=kz$$